# Is possible to use multiple taxonomy terms name (not tids) as contextual filter in Views?

Tags: views

For example: `example.com/TermName1+TermName2+TermName3`.

It seems that the "Allow multiple values" option only works with tids.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late for this to matter, but you may be able to do this with `hook_views_pre_view()`.

Possible example:

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if (!empty($args)) {
    // change the argument to term IDs
    $term_names = explode('+', $args[0]);
    foreach ($term_names as $term) {
      $terms[] = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term)->tid;
    }
    $view->args[0] = implode('+', $terms);
  }
}
```